# can there be problems due to the wrong order in fr""?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, format, rawstring

I can do `fr""` and `rf""` in python.
**As far as I understand, here the order may be important, but I would like to understand if this is so?**
And if that is, then I want to see an example, which will show possible problems.
It would also be interesting to hear about order issues, including the remaining `u` and `b`.
For example, `fbr`, what about it?

Comment: you cannot combine `b` with `f`... in any case, the order shouldn't matter and in Python 3, `u` doesn't do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of `f` and `r` doesn't matter. Here's what I found from the [docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#specification):

> 'f' may be combined with 'r' or 'R', in either order, to produce raw f-string literals. 'f' may not be combined with 'b': this PEP does not propose to add binary f-strings. 'f' may not be combined with 'u'.